# Translate a path in Metapost

Tags: eps, metapost

Is there a way to **draw** a **path** that was defined by relationships between **pairs centered around a specific point**?

I basically want to create a path that I can translate anywhere I want in my image.

Thank you!

Comment: `path mypath; mypath=<instructions>; draw mypath shifted (3,5);`

Comment: That works provided you know the coordinates that the path is drawn So is there a way to define a starting point for your path?

Comment: Doesn't my example below help? With `<instructions>` I mean any path creation commands.

Comment: And if it did help, don't forget to mark his answer as "accepted" :-)

Answer (score 9):

You can save the path in a variable and transform it. Example:

```
path mypath;

beginfig(1);
z1=(10,-10);
x1=-x4; y1=y4;
x2=x1; y2=-y1;
z3=-z1;

mypath = z1--z3--z2--z4--cycle;

draw mypath;

draw mypath shifted z2;
endfig;

end
```

[image]